# How to create user with MySQL Workbench when username is an e-mail address?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

From the MySQL command line, I can execute the following SQL to create a user whose username is his e-mail address:

```
CREATE USER 'julio@gmail.com'@'%'
IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

However, I need to create the users from the Schema Privileges section of the MySQL Workbench and then forward engineer them into a database.

[image]

I am using Workbench 6.1 Community Edition and MySQL Server 5.6.  I have tried several different formats for the usernames but all of them create the wrong user or fail when I try to forward engineer them.

```
julio@gmail.com - makes the user julio at the host gmail.com
'julio@gmail.com' - attempts to make the user ''julio'@'gmail.com'' which simply fails
'julio@gmail.com'@'%' - also fails
```

How can I create a user from the MySQL Workbench when the user name is an e-mail address?

Comment: `CREATE USER 'julio@gmail.com'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'` worked for me (MySQL Workbench 6.1.4 CE, MySQL 5.6.16 on Windows 8.1).

Comment: @VMai, I don't want to manually type and execute the query from the WorkBench. I can do that from the command line. I want to create the users from the "Schema Privileges" section of the Workbench. I edited my post to show that.

Comment: I tested this, MySQL Workbench 6.1.6, using the GUI instead of executing a `CREATE USER` statement. It worked fine for me.

Comment: @BillKarwin what format did you use when you tested it?  When I use julio@gmail.com for the username and forward engineer it, I get user julio at host gmail.com.  That is not what I need.  I need it to be user julio@gmail.com at host %

Comment: See examples in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I find no problem using MySQL Workbench 6.1.6 to create a user with an `@` character.

I can subsequently query `mysql.user` and see the user name as I entered it.

```
mysql> select host, user from mysql.user where user like 'j%';
+------+-----------------+
| host | user            |
+------+-----------------+
| %    | julio@gmail.com |
+------+-----------------+
```

I can grant privileges to the user.

```
mysql> grant all privileges on test.* to 'julio@gmail.com'@'%';
```

I can also connect with the command-line client:

```
$ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u julio@gmail.com -p
```

Here's a screen shot of creating the user:

[image]